# How can I make a Android VR Video player that converts local videos to VR

Tags: android, virtual-reality, vrvideoview

I want to display a 2d video in such a way that it divides the screen into two and adds a Vr lense effect so that users can use a vr box to view the video in 3d

An app like : [iPlay VR Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.panagola.app.iplay)

If you could give me some pointers, I would be grateful.<3